# How to partially round corners of given block with box-shadow, and keep unrounded corners with unrounded box-shadow (webkit and gecko)?

Tags: css

I have a `div` with multiple borders, and for one border I am using `box-shadow`. I want this `div` to have a few rounded corners with one square corner. However, whenever one corner has a `border-radius` added to it (other than `0`), the other corners of `box-shadow` become rounded as well (with a different radius than any of the specified values for `border-radius`). Is there a way to set `border-radius` for some corners, but not all, and have the `box-shadow` use the same radius as the `border` for all corners?

This behavior is present in Chrome 19, Firefox 13, and Safari 5, but it is *not* present in Internet Explorer 9 or Opera 12, which both display the `box-shadow` as expected—with a square corner for the `box-shadow` when the `border`'s corner is also square.

### Code ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/3CRLk/)):

#### CSS

```css
.block1 {
    padding: 18px 14px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 57, 47, .32);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 57, 47, .32);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 57, 47, .32);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
.block2 {
    padding: 18px 14px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 57, 47, .32);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 57, 47, .32);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 57, 47, .32);
}
.outer {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<p>Top-right block corner is not rounded, but box-shadow is:</p>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="block1">
        foo
    </div>
</div>

<p>Box-shadow on block without border-radius:</p>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="block2">
        bar
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since the shadow doesn't fade in your example, would a thick border be a reasonable fix for this? Not sure if the red border was for the demo or in your actual code: http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/3efB5/5/

Comment: I have to have multiple borders on one element - red border was mandatory, and also I needed one more border. I can workaround this with pseudo-element, but problem itself will still exist. Though I think that more appropriate place for this question is in webkit and mozilla bugtrackers...

Comment: Interesting test case. I was going to suggest outline to get your second border but border radius doesn't seem to apply to that at all (in chrome at least).

Comment: @only, yes, this definitely looks like a bug. And if it's not a bug with the engine, I'd say it's a bug with the spec (imo).

Comment: @only, could you ping me when you submit the bug reports and post the links to the reports? (Or let me know if you don't plan to report the bug.)

Comment: @bfrohs, I`ll try to make bug reports, thought I never did this before. And I`ll let you know the results.

Comment: @bfrohs, in Firefox Nightly this bug is already gone. And I`ve submitted it in webkit bugtracker [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91323).

Answer (score 2):

Use an `inset` shadow on the outer div. Looks good in chrome.

fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/G2bvw/1/

**Updated**: If you want a solid shadow, you don't want inset shadow on the outer div and the red border is a must, this should work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/G2bvw/3/

The trick is to use the border as shadow and the shadow as border.

Comment: you beat me to it, [here's mine](http://jsfiddle.net/3efB5/10/) using the OP's code, just switch the border and box-shadows around

Comment: .outer div was for demo purpose only, I can`t put any shadow on it, all styles should be applied to one element - .block1

Comment: @stephenmurdoch, that`s right! This is almost it, but we have bug in Opera now, awful rendering problem in IE9 and little problem in Chrome. In Chrome compare [initial block](http://jsfiddle.net/3efB5/2/) and [your solution tweaked](http://jsfiddle.net/3efB5/23/) - border in solution rounded a little bit more (looks like 1px difference) than outer shadow on initial block. Still working on it but seems like it will be hard if even possible to make this solution look same as initial block crossbrowser... Also this solution will not be acceptable if outer shadow have a blur.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch, and one more thing. If block background and background of a body will be different - things will go wrong, as background of a block spreads on semitransparent border...

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS instead ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/3CRLk/4/), [comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/3CRLk/3/)):

```css
.block-fixed {

    background: #fff;

    /* Have to increase padding by 1px for inset box-shadow */
    padding: 19px 15px;

    /* Use border for outer border */
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 57, 47, .32);

    /* Use box-shadow for inner border */
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px red;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px red;

    /* Have to adjust border-radius due to switching shadow/border */
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;

}
```

Comment: Check all comments on previous answer - too many problems to accept this solution. This solution is sort of a hack, a workaround that usefull only in limited number of usecases. I think that it is impossible to answer this question, because it is simply a bug. Or answer is - fix a bug in a browsers.